# Bridging two tap interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I am a total noob, this is my first ever experiment with kernel networking. I am attempting to create a bridge between two `tap` interfaces, and try to send traffic through. It is more of an experiment than for any particular purpose.

```
$ brctl showstp br0
br0
bridge id      8000.46846e0c0ff9
designated root    8000.46846e0c0ff9
root port         0            path cost          0
max age          20.00         bridge max age        20.00
hello time        2.00         bridge hello time      2.00
forward delay        15.00         bridge forward delay      15.00
ageing time         300.00
hello timer           1.98         tcn timer          0.00
topology change timer     0.00         gc timer         115.04
flags          


tap1 (1)
port id        8001            state            forwarding
designated root    8000.46846e0c0ff9   path cost        100
designated bridge  8000.46846e0c0ff9   message age timer      0.00
designated port    8001            forward delay timer   10.34
designated cost       0            hold timer         0.98
flags          

tap2 (2)
port id        8002            state            forwarding
designated root    8000.46846e0c0ff9   path cost        100
designated bridge  8000.46846e0c0ff9   message age timer      0.00
designated port    8002            forward delay timer    0.00
designated cost       0            hold timer         0.98
flags
```

I have the bridge  `br0` created, with both `tap1` and `tap2` added. I have a program injecting ARP packets into `tap1` using `libpcap`. Wireshark correctly shows the packets entering `tap1`. However, no packet shows up at `tap2`. I tried adding the follwing rule  in ebtables:

`sudo ebtables -I INPUT --log --log-level debug`

No packets show up in the logs. I'll appreciate any inputs.

EDIT: Adding more information. Injecting fake packets is indeed the application. My intention here is to simulate, fully in software and without VMs, how packets get forwarded through the linux kernel stack. I am not creating any new network namespaces. Perhaps that's the problem?

I only have two processes. The "read" process has a file descriptor open to `tap2`, and constantly tries to read from it. The write process has a file descriptor open to `tap1` and waits for user prompt to send out the ARP query. The ARP query has a random source IP address. The source MAC address is set as the MAC address of `tap1`. Here is the output of tcpdump:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tap1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^[[A07:19:57.752990 ARP, Request who-has google-public-dns-a.google.com tell 0.0.248.17, length 28
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff ba9c 0589 16ad 0806 0001
    0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 ba9c 0589 16ad 0000 f811
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0808 0808
```

I have configured `tap1` and `tap2` to not have IP addresses. Could that be the problem?

```
brctl addbr br0
ip tuntap add name tap1 mode tap
ip tuntap add name tap2 mode tap
brctl addif br0 tap1
brctl addif br0 tap2
ifconfig tap1 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig tap2 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig br0 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.1.255
ip link set br0 up
ip link set tap1 up
ip link set tap2 up
```

Based on the answer, I checked attaching various applications to `tap2`. I notice this: when no application is using `tap1` or `tap2`, both interfaces don't have the LOWER_UP flag set.

```
4: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 46:84:6e:0c:0f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: tap1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/ether ba:9c:05:89:16:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
26: tap2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
```

When I start the applications, the LOWER_UP flag becomes set:

```
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 46:84:6e:0c:0f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: tap1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/ether ba:9c:05:89:16:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
26: tap2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/ether 46:84:6e:0c:0f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I'm sorry this is turning out to be lengthy, I'm just hoping that there is enough information to make sense of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case, because you said you are a total noob: A tun (layer 3) or tap (layer 2) interface is the network interface endpoint of an application, and the application can read and write packets from this network interface. What you create with `ip tuntap add ...` or the outdated `tunctl` are *persistent names* for such endpoints, and you'll normally still run the application, and it won't do anything unless you run the application.

As the application interacts with the network interface as a matter of design, there's no need to "inject" packets with a third party application, unless you mean by "inject' this normal interaction I described.

Also, if you want to play around with networking, I can recommend using *network namespaces* and *veth pairs*. Basically you can set up a lot of virtual computers on your computer that can mimic communication between real computers on a network.

So if you want to do that, and don't want to play with your own application creating and receiving packets, you don't need a tun/tap interface.

That said, I just tested your setup, with a slight variation because you didn't say what you use to "inject" packets: I used two `socat`s to create to tap endpoint `tap0a` and `tap1a`, then I bridged them, and used another two `socat`s in two different namespaces to create the correct packets for me. They need to be in a different namespace, as local packets will always be delivered via loopback `lo`.

And as expected, bridging tap devices works just fine.

So I suppose the problem is in the packet you are injecting: Wrong ethernet address, or no broadcast. Please edit your question with with `tcpdump -xx ...` output when you inject the ARP packet.

Or possibly you'd like to create network namespaces and bridge two endpoints of two veth-pairs instead? That's a lot simpler.

**Edit**

The ARP packet looks good. It seems like there's no application connected to `tap2`. If you do `ip link`, you shouldn't see a `LOWER_UP` flag for `tap2`. Guess: The bridge detects that the device is only partially up, and doesn't send packets to this port.

Try replacing it with a `tap` that *has* an application connected to it, something like

```
sudo socat TUN:10.0.2.2/24,tun-name=tapx,tun-type=tap,iff-up - | hexdump -C
```

(the `10.0.2.2/24` address doesn't do anything, but `socat` won't work if you don't specify an address), and in another terminal

```
sudo ip link set tapx master br0
```

(that replaces `brctl addif`), then inject your packet several times and see if you get a hexdump in the first window. Also check for `LOWER_UP` with `ip link show dev tapx`.

BTW, `ifconfig` and `brctl` are outdated. Use `ip` and `bridge` instead.

Not assigning IP addresses to the ports of the bridge doesn't matter, because bridge ports **don't have IP addresses** (if they got some assigned to them before they became enslaved by a bridge, they are ignored). See e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1219223/linux-bridge-network-influenced-by-route-table/1219486).

Comment: I've added the details. Could you please check?

Comment: Turns out the reverse is true. `tap2` has an application using it, but not `tap1`. Whenever an application connects to an interface, LOWER_UP gets set. Is that an indication of the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the the help so far! I haven't marked the answer as accepted, just in case someone can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bunch with this and think I've arrived at a solution. Or, at least, a better understanding of what's going on.

It's important to keep in mind that the only way to deliver a packet to a tap interface on the receive side ("RX") is by writing that packet to the socket descriptor *created by the process that opened the tap* (via `open("/dev/net/tun",...)` and `ioctl`). Only one process can have this file descriptor at once. If a tap device is open, and another process tries to re-open another tap device with the same name, that system call will fail.

So when you have any other process, like wireshark, opening a raw socket and then binding *that* to `tap0`, it's only capable of writing traffic **out** of the system (from the perspective of the kernel). That is, wireshark should be bumping the `TX` counter of `tap0`, and only `RX` packets will be forwarded to the bridged interface.

You can check the counters for each like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for if in tap{0,1}; do
    stats=/sys/class/net/$if/statistics/
    rx=$(cat $stats/rx_packets)
    tx=$(cat $stats/tx_packets)
    echo "$if: rx=$rx, tx=$tx"
done
```

which outputs something like:

```
tap0: rx=0, tx=6
tap1: rx=0, tx=5
```

So in your specific case, I suspect that the problem is here:

> I have a program injecting `ARP` packets into `tap1` using libpcap. Wireshark correctly shows the packets entering `tap1`. However, no packet shows up at `tap2`.

How are you injecting ARP packets into tap1? I assume wireshark isn't calling `fd = open("/dev/net/tun", ...)` and `ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, ...)`, so the packets sent will be TX, and therefore not bridged.

You'll need the program that opens `tap0` to write packets to `tap0`'s file descriptor to get those packets to be forwarded on `br0` and show up on `tap1`.